# Can "galaxy" sometime mean "solar (or stellar) system" in English?

Tags: translation

In various large public forums about astronomy or astrophysics, from time to time I see people using the word "galaxy" for what seems to not mean the galactic set of stars (like Milky Way or Andromeda) but our (or any) Solar system.

-> is it a "legal" use of the word galaxy in English ?
is it a wrong but popular use ?
Or is it just wrong thoughts by ignorant users ?

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thank you for your question. There are no "laws" in force, but [**_galaxy_**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/galaxy) means _A system of millions or billions of stars, together with gas and dust, held together by gravitational attraction._ It certainly can't describe the solar system. Our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages provide advice on writing useful questions and answers. We hope you will ask more questions!

Comment: I would say *"legal"* is a too strong of a word in this question.

Comment: Can you provide an example?  It's hard for this native speaker to imagine any native speaker using "galaxy" to mean "solar system".

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is improper to use galaxy to refer to a solar system:

[Galaxy](http://users.skynet.be/sky03361/dictionary/dictionary.html):

> - a large system of about 100 billion stars. ***Our Sun is a member of the Milky Way Galaxy***. There are billions of galaxies in the observable universe. Exactly when and how galaxies formed in the Universe is a topic of current astronomical research.
> - Galaxies are found in a variety of sizes and shapes. ***Our own Milky Way galaxy is spiral in shape and contains several billion stars***. Some galaxies are so distant their light takes millions of years to reach the Earth. Galaxies are classified in three main groups; spirals, ellipticals and irregulars.

Astronomy Dictionary